# Howto reusing Form Request inside loop

Tags: laravel, laravel-8

I am making a "/bulk" endpoint for my API/REST made in Laravel 8.
My problem is that I don't know how to reuse the same FormRequest that I have for the create or update

json post to: /cars/bulk

```json
{
"cars": [{"model": "A", "year": 2021, "plate": "AA11BB"},{"model": "B", "year": 2021, "plate": "AA12BB"},{"model": "C", "plate": "AA13BB"}]
}
```

```
// CarController.php
public function store(CarRequest $request)
{
    $car = $this->carService->store($request, Car::class);
}

public function update(CarRequest $request, Car $car)
{
    $this->carService->update($request, $car);
}

public function bulk(Request $request)
{
    $this->carService->bulk($request);
}
```

```
// CarService.php
public function store($request, $modelClass)
{
    # My code....
}

public function update($request, $model)
{
    # My code....
}

public function bulk($request)
{
    foreach ($request->cars AS $carData )
    {
        $car = Car::where('plate','=',$carData->plate)->first()

        # here is the problem, 
        # howto validate each $car by reusing CarRequest

        if ($car){
            $this->update($carData, $car);
        } else {
            $this->store($carData, Car::class);
        }


    }
}
```

This is de form request for each item, i have use to for bulk or one request

```php
class CarRequest extends BaseRequest
{


    public function authorize()
    {

        $this->setModel(Car::class);
        return $this->isAuthorized();
    }


    public function rules()
    {
        $this->setModel(Car::class);
        $rules = parent::rules();

        $rules = [
            'model' => 'required',
            'year'  => 'required|numeric',
            'plate' => 'required'
        ];

        return $rules;
    }

    public function messages()
    {
        # multiples messages
    }
}
```

I need reuse my request

Edit: add form request

Comment: Can you please share your validation for single items and i might be able to adjust for bulk.

Answer (score 0):

So I wouldn't suggest using it within a loop how you have in your example, what would be better would be to create a second, bulk request that valiates an array like this.

```
public function rules()
    {
        $this->setModel(Car::class);
        $rules = parent::rules();

        $rules = [
            'cars' => ['required', 'array'],
            'cars.*.model' => 'required',
            'cars.*.year'  => 'required|numeric',
            'cars.*.plate' => 'required'
        ];

        return $rules;
    }
```

Comment: I thought about it, but I should keep 2 form request, in case I have to modify them

Comment: I mean theoretically you wouldn't need a the single endpoint as you could just send one item in the array, that way it reduces the amount of form requests. 

The problem with what you are trying to acheive in yours is that you are validating inside a loop, so some of your items could succeed but then the request would fail, so if you then tried again with correct data it would create duplicate records.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with same CarRequest form request class as follows.

```
public function rules()
{
    return[
        'cars.*.model' => 'required',
        'cars.*.year' => 'required',
        'cars.*.plate' => 'required',
    ];

}
```

Laravel will expect that you are sending nested array. If you dont want to mix it up with CarRequest you can do it with creating another FormRequest class.

Comment: I like have rules on unique placer, for not modify two request.